# Make sure that using a regular expression is safe here. SonarQube

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube FAILED due to - Make sure that using a regular expression is safe here.

How we can ensure regular expression is safe in Node.js?

[image]

```js
// Special characters like (/[(){}#@!?;:) are not allowed
const regex = new RegExp('(^[^\\/\\[\\]\\(\\):\\{\\}#@!?\\s\\\\;]+$)', 'g');

// Check
let isValid = regex.test("Test-123");
console.log("isValid :>>", isValid);
```